# Dockerized tomcat webapp throwing 404 exception when connecting to another localhost URL

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I've got an application running in tomcat 8.5 in a docker container.  Java version is jdk 8. There is a properties file that the app uses that points to another running service.  In this case, I have the service running on my host machine and the property is set to point to my localhost:

```
my.external.service.url=http://localhost:8080/my-api-service
```

When my tomcat app is also running on the host machine, this works fine.  But when my app runs in the docker container, I get a 404 error when it tries to call this service.

I tried switching the URL to point to my machine name:

```
my.external.service.url=http://my.pc.url.com:8080/my-api-service
```

But in this case, even though it still works if the tomcat app is running on the host instead of the docker container, I get a different error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: my.pc.url.com: No address associated with hostname
```

How do I configure the container so that I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the specific error you got - `No address associated with the hostname` - that means it cannot resolve the hostname to an IP. So you can find you local host IP and then pass an argument to the docker run command to add that host to the container lookup. Eg: `-add-host="my.pc.url.com:X.X.X.X"`

Docker networking is a potentially complex thing. Basically, if you run two separate containers they will not 'see' each other. You could have them both expose ports on the host machine and have then 'connect' that way, but you are better using the networking features of docker to ensure the containers talk to each other.

For a simple example like you have - say just two containers running tomcats that you would like to talk to each other - you might be best to just run them both via docker-compose so that they are in the same network.

There are many resources on the internet to explain the further details of docker networking if you wish to explore.

Comment: The thing is I don't want my api service in a docker container.  I want it running on the host machine, because that's the code I'm developing and changing on the fly constantly.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then. Looking at the error - No address associated with the hostname - that means it cannot resolve the hostname to an IP. So you can find you local host IP and then pass an argument to the docker run command to add that host to the container lookup. Eg: -add-host="my.pc.url.com:X.X.X.X"

Comment: thanks, I got it. If you want to make that a separate answer, I'll check it off as the accepted answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think the other info might still be useful, so left that too.